# How to do custom drawing on a Bitmap / BitmapField on the BlackBerry?

Tags: graphics, blackberry

I want to do something relatively simple:  I want to create a Bitmap object entirely in code, draw on it (lines, text, ellipses, rectangles, points etc.), and display it in a BitmapField on the BlackBerry screen.

Can anyone give me a simple code sample that shows how to do this, or a link to a good sample project?

**Update:**  I have this code sample, but it uses a deprecated constructor for `Graphics`:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100);
Graphics g = new Graphics(bmp);
g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
BitmapField bmpField = new BitmapField(bmp);
add(bmpField);
```

How do I do the same thing, only without using the `Graphics` constructor that takes a `Bitmap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the static factory method on the Graphics class: `Graphics.create(Bitmap)`

Answer (score 2):

override the paint method:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100) {
   public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
      graphics.clear();
      // write your code here
      super.paint(graphics);
   }   
};
```

Comment: I think you mean BitmapField instead of Bitmap